# Prevent AVCONV from upgrading A/V quality

Tags: audio, video, resolution, libav

I am trying to convert all video files of different formats and qualities into one semi-standard format. Thankfully avconv makes this reasonably easy. This is the command that I am using:

```
IFS=$'\n'; 
for i in *; 
    do avconv -stats -y -i $i -acodec ac3 -ab 192k -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -s:v 1136x640 converted/${i%%.*}.mp4;
done
```

However, there is one issue: Since all the source files are of different qualities, it is sometimes possible that the source files have a lower resolution or audio quality than the parameters that I use (192k/1136x640). It seems to me like when we have a source file that is, for example, 161k/640x480 avconv will attempt to increase its resolution and audio bitrate. I could be wrong about this though, if so please correct me.

I am wondering if there is an easy way (i.e. a command line argument for avconv) that would "do the right thing" so that then the source file is 256k/1920x1080 it would convert it to 192k/1136x640, but when the source file is 161k/640x480 then it would just convert it to 161k/640x480 in the given format? As of right now I just have a python script that uses mediainfo to get the information and then automatically selects the right audio bitrate and resolution before passing those as parameters to avconv.

Thank you in advance!